# How to remove some (not all) leading zeros in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've a `varchar` column in my `SQL` table and it's formatted in the following way:

- 000001
- 006420
- 000100
- 009999

I need to change this format when querying the table so that it's displayed like the format below:

- 0001
- 6420
- 0100
- 9999

***You'll notice that the new format has 2 of the leading zeros removed.***

I've attempted this myself by using the following methods:

```
RIGHT(ColumnName, 4) AS NewColumnFormat
SUBSTRING(ColumnName, 3, 4) AS NewColumnFormat
```

But when I apply this to a number like **000010** it's appearing as **0001** and a number like **000001** is appearing as **0000** and so on.

Below is the query I've been using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1000
    SUBSTRING(H.EMPREF, 3, 4) AS NewColumnFormat
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN H1.[NEWVALUE] = 'E' THEN 'Employee' ELSE H1.[NEWVALUE] END FROM [HISTORY] H1 WHERE H1.[FIELDNAME] = 'EMPTYPE' AND H.[EMPREF] = H1.[EMPREF] ORDER BY H1.CHANGEDATE DESC) AS EMPTYPE
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 H2.[NEWVALUE] FROM [HISTORY] H2 WHERE H2.[FIELDNAME] = 'TITLE' AND H.[EMPREF] = H2.[EMPREF] ORDER BY H2.CHANGEDATE DESC) AS TITLE
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 H3.[NEWVALUE] FROM [HISTORY] H3 WHERE H3.[FIELDNAME] = 'FIRSTNAMES' AND H.[EMPREF] = H3.[EMPREF] ORDER BY H3.CHANGEDATE DESC) AS FIRSTNAMES
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 H4.[NEWVALUE] FROM [HISTORY] H4 WHERE H4.[FIELDNAME] = 'SURNAME' AND H.[EMPREF] = H4.[EMPREF] ORDER BY H4.CHANGEDATE DESC) AS SURNAME
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 H5.[NEWVALUE] FROM [HISTORY] H5 WHERE H5.[FIELDNAME] = 'DEPARTMENT' AND H.[EMPREF] = H5.[EMPREF] ORDER BY H5.CHANGEDATE DESC) AS DEPARTMENT
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 H6.[NEWVALUE] FROM [HISTORY] H6 WHERE H6.[FIELDNAME] = 'SECTIONMGR' AND H.[EMPREF] = H6.[EMPREF] ORDER BY H6.CHANGEDATE DESC) AS SECTIONMGR
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 H7.[NEWVALUE] FROM [HISTORY] H7 WHERE H7.[FIELDNAME] = 'HR2' AND H.[EMPREF] = H7.[EMPREF] ORDER BY H7.CHANGEDATE DESC) AS HR2
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 H9.[NEWVALUE] FROM [HISTORY] H9 WHERE H9.[FIELDNAME] = 'JOBTITLE' AND H.[EMPREF] = H9.[EMPREF] ORDER BY H9.CHANGEDATE DESC) AS JOBTITLE
FROM 
    [HISTORY] H
WHERE (H.TABLENAME = 'EMP' OR H.TABLENAME = 'OD' OR H.TABLENAME = 'SMS' OR H.TABLENAME = 'JD')
ORDER BY NewColumnFormat
```

I get the following output:

```
+-----------------+----------+-------+------------+---------+------------+------------+------+----------+
| NewColumnFormat | EMPTYPE  | TITLE | FIRSTNAMES | SURNAME | DEPARTMENT | SECTIONMGR | HR2  | JOBTITLE |
+-----------------+----------+-------+------------+---------+------------+------------+------+----------+
|            0000 | Employee | Mr    | Test       | Record  | LB         |            | NULL |          |
|            0001 | Employee | Mr    | Test       | Record  | AB         |            | NULL |          |
|            0002 | Employee | Mr    | Test       | Record  | LB         |            | NULL |          |
|            0003 | Employee | Mr    | Test       | Record  | LB         |            | NULL |          |
|            0004 | Employee | Mr    | Test       | Record  | BO         |            | NULL |          |
|            0005 | Employee | Mr    | Test       | Record  | BO         |            | NULL |          |
|            0006 | Employee | Mr    | Test       | Record  | AB         |            | NULL |          |
|            0007 | Employee | Mr    | Test       | Record  | RET        |            | NULL |          |
|            0008 | Employee | Mr    | Test       | Record  | DES        |            | NULL |          |
+-----------------+----------+-------+------------+---------+------------+------------+------+----------+
```

Where am I going wrong that the format of the "NewColumnFormat" is displaying incorrectly?

Comment: Add EMPREF to your select and update your "i get the following output" and I'll tell you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT FORMAT(12, '0000') as pad_to_4
--> 0012

SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(INT, '12'), '0000') as pad_to_4
--> 0012

SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(INT, '000012'), '0000') as pad_to_4
--> 0012
```

Numbers longer than 4 stay as is (or lose leading zeroes):

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(INT, '123456'), '0000') as pad_to_4
--> 123456

SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(INT, '00123456'), '0000') as pad_to_4
--> 123456
```

> But when I apply this to a number like 000010 it's appearing as 0001 and a number like 000001 is appearing as 0000 and so on.

I wasn't able to reproduce your complaint , by the way:

```
SELECT RIGHT('000010', 4) AS NewColumnFormat
--> 0010

SELECT SUBSTRING('000010', 3, 4) AS NewColumnFormat
--> 0010
```

Which makes me think the basic problem is something along the lines of the EMPREF not being what you think it is..

Comment: The `SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(INT, '12'), '0000') as pad_to_4` suggestion resolved my issue and I'm getting the results to display correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE MyTable
**SET** ColumnName= RIGHT(ColumnName, LEN(ColumnName) - 2);

Please let me know your outcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LPAD (0000012,4,0)
--> 0012
```

Comment: `LPAD` appears to be available in Mysql and pl-sql, but Isn't implemented in SQL Server (which the question is tagged as)